# Stopping / Killing a debug thread in IntelliJ

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I like to stop the execution of a debug thread that I run in `IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.3`.

I can stop the entire JVM process, but that will require to restart the web application that takes a lot of time to spin up.

I found [this request](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206823585-Interrupt-or-kill-thread-currently-being-suspended-at-breakpoint-) for such a feature (back from 2015), but I see no new way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried to use "Run | Debugging actions | Throw Exception" action and throw "InterruptedException"?

Answer (score 2):

Following y.bedrov comment, the solution was indeed to get to the "Throw Exception" wizard and then to enter there

`new RuntimeException("error")`